# Teams call notification coming after call ends

Tags: call, microsoft-teams, call-recording, microsoft-graph-api

I subscribed to MS [call records](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) notifications (changeType - created)

As per this , I should get notification on call creation, but I am getting notification on call ending.

I started a call and continued it for 1 hour, I got notification after it ended.

Is it expected behavior ?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http):

> The call record is available only after the associated call is
> completed.

It means that the call record resource is created after the call is completed and then you will receive a notification.

Comment: oh I had different understanding of "created" type notification. 
Thanks.
Now my doubt is in which case updated notification is received from Microsoft.
As this record is created after call ends and all its properties are set like audio jitter, packetloss. Now in which case this record will be updated and we will get updated notification ?

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little about your question?